# I want to show image in new window as soon as image is clicked in mainwindow qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want to display my image in a new window . So i am trying to pass the path of the image as value through constructor

```
void DicomWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    qDebug() << ui->diWidget->whatsThis();
    QString path = ui->diWidget->whatsThis();
    EditWindow * editWindow = new EditWindow(this);
    editWindow->setWindowTitle(path);
    editWindow->setWhatsThis(path);
    editWindow->show();
}
```

I want to pass the path in constructor but if I do the UI of the editwindow is not rendering

my editwindow.cpp

```
#include "editwindow.h"
#include "ui_editwindow.h"

EditWindow::EditWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::EditWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

EditWindow::~EditWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

//Here i need to have refernce to this how shoul i give it
EditWindow::EditWindow(QString& filepath){
    QFile file (filepath);
    QFileInfo fileInfo(file.fileName());
    QString filename(fileInfo.fileName());
    QString name = filename;
    currentDicomPath = filepath;
}

void EditWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    currentDicomPath =  EditWindow::windowTitle();
    qDebug() <<"Hello9" << currentDicomPath;
}
```

Comment: Do you really store the path to the image in [QWidget::whatsThis()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#whatsThis-prop)? I doubt so...

Comment: I tried passing through constructor but I cannot pass it along the constructors, If i do so the new window is not rendering

Answer (score 0):

By rewriting the constructor with `EditWindow::EditWindow(QString& filepath)` the Qt constructor with `EditWindow::EditWindow(QWidget *parent)` won't run, and thus you can't see any rendering.

Consider amending the existing constructor with something like `EditWindow::EditWindow(QWidget *parent, QString& filepath)` and add your custom code below `ui->setup(this);`

After that, you are able to initiate your class with `EditWindow* editWindow = new EditWindow(this, filepath);`

Otherwise, you just created an [overload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)#C++) of the existing constructor.